# Are these PL/SQL variable initializations equivalent?

Tags: oracle, plsql, variable-assignment, default-value

So I know I can initialize variables in PL/SQL using either of the following:

- The `DEFAULT` keyword
- The `:=` assignment operator

For example:

- `counter binary_integer DEFAULT 15;`
- `counter binary_integer := 15;`

Are these two methods *exactly* equivalent to the PL/SQL engine, or are there any slight differences?

Comment: Can you share a more complete snippet please?

Comment: They are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are equivalent.

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CHDFADII)

> You can use the keyword DEFAULT instead of the assignment operator to
>   initialize variables. You can also use DEFAULT to initialize
>   subprogram parameters, cursor parameters, and fields in a user-defined
>   record.
>
> Use DEFAULT for variables that have a typical value. Use the
>   assignment operator for variables (such as counters and accumulators)
>   that have no typical value.
>
> Example 2-8 Assigning Default Values to Variables with DEFAULT Keyword

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    blood_type CHAR DEFAULT 'O';         -- Same as blood_type CHAR := 'O';
  3  
  4    hours_worked    INTEGER DEFAULT 40;  -- Typical value
  5    employee_count  INTEGER := 0;        -- No typical value
  6  
  7  BEGIN
  8    NULL;
  9  END;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: So then this means that the usage is meant to be different, even if the result is identical.  "Typical value" is a little hand-wavy, though.

Comment: I've never used `DEFAULT` as `:=` is 5 less characters to type. I can kind of see what they mean by "typical" vs. "no typical", i.e. the intention is that using `DEFAULT` is meant to be a self-documenting thing that says "this is the normal value for this variable, but it might be overridden", whereas `:=` means "this is the starting value for this variable, but it is expected to be changed, possibly many times (as in a loop)".

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#CIHHEIGG) you can use either:

> To specify the initial value, use either the assignment operator (:=) or the keyword DEFAULT, followed by an expression

which means they are equivalent.